# chart.js add events note based on day

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've created a basic line graph using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/)with values distributed on time and I would like to add info about events that occurred on the same days.

This is the datasets used:

```
  return {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Kb',
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: '#2d627c',
        data: data,
        borderColor: '#79a6bc',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointStyle: 'circle',
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointBorderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
      },
      {
        label: 'Events',
        type: 'bar',
        pointStyle: 'circle',
        pointRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
        data: events,

      }
    ]
  }
```

Do you have any suggestions to add info on the day event?

Thanks a lot!

[image]